# How to getRange for rows containing text in Column A

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Let's say I have two columns, in Column A I have Months, in Column B I have ID's. The amount of rows per month is changing day to day so I want a google script that will select the range of rows in Column A that match a specific month.

I can't seem to find how to do it using getRange or RangeList.

I have a script that will allow me to **move** range of cells from Sheet 1 to Sheet 2 based on a range but what I want to do is change it so it **copies** cells from Sheet 1 to 2 **where the text in Column A is "January"**

```
function CopyTickets2() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var firstSheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[1];
var secondSheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];


spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(firstSheet)
spreadsheet.getRange("B2:B70").moveTo(spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(secondSheet).getRange("A14:A100"));
spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(firstSheet)
spreadsheet.getRange("C2:C70").moveTo(spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(secondSheet).getRange("B14:B100"));
spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(secondSheet)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround using this as a formula

```
=query(DATASHEET!A:C, "where A = 'JANUARY' ",0)
```